# Bivariate normal distribtuion to chi(2)-distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We are given that $\textbf{X} = (X_1, X_2)'$ has the mean vector $\mu = (0,0)'$ and the covariance matrix
$$
 C = \begin{bmatrix}1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

I want to show that the random variable $Y = \frac{X_1^2 - 2\rho X_1X_2 + X_2^2}{1-\rho^2}$ is $\chi(2)$-distributed. I suspect this can be done by examining the characteristic function or the moment generating function.

Thanks in advance for all help!

Answer (score 0):

We can write $X_2 = \rho X_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} X_3$ where $X_1$ and $X_3$ are independent standard normal random variables.  Then 
$Y = X_1^2 + X_3^2$.